# SQL: dealing with NULL values (union)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, null, union

Given this two, similar, queries:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM to_date) AS year_expired
        FROM     salaries
        GROUP BY year_expired
        ORDER BY year_expired
```

and

```
(
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM to_date) AS year_expired
          FROM salaries
          WHERE EXTRACT (YEAR FROM to_date) > 1990
          GROUP BY year_expired
          ORDER BY year_expired
)
UNION
(
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM to_date) AS year_expired
          FROM salaries
          WHERE EXTRACT (YEAR FROM to_date) <= 1990
          GROUP BY year_expired
          ORDER BY year_expired
)
```

The output in the **first** query gives a row with NULL value into the `year_expire` field, while in the second there is no NULL row.

[You can see the example here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmbCs.png)

I'm asking myself why this happens. Does the `GROUP BY` also takes NULL values? 
I know that the UNION threats the table as a set, and thus it doesn't select duplicates.

How does UNION handle NULL values, and how does GROUP BY handle NULL values?

EDIT: I changed the second query (the second column was wrong)

**EDIT2:** Thanks for the answer, but could you explain what's the difference?
I thought that it might be because of the WHERE CLAUSE: with the comparison if we have a NULL value it becomes UNKNOWN and that's why the WHERE clause doesn't take into account the NULL.

Could you tell me at least if what I said is what happens?

PS: I'm using PostgresSQL.

Comment: NULL is grouped in GROUP BY. NULL is included in UNION. But @GordonLinoff is directing you towards the real problem.

Comment: @JacobH thanks for the answer, could you answer the question on EDIT2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the `UNION`.  You are filtering out the `NULL` values with the `WHERE` clauses.

The two queries are not identical.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I edited the question by removing the second column (in the second query), that I wrote down wrongly.
Could you tell me if your answer still holds, and if yes why? 
Because it seems actually the same since we are just doing an `UNION` between `year_expired > 1990` and `year_expired <= 1990`(which logically gives the whole range of years)

Comment: The answer is exactly the same.  You need to learn about null values.

Comment: I tried to answer myself, is this what happens? (EDIT2)

Answer (score 0):

You are using comparison operators `>`, `<=` in second query and no filters in first query. It won't consider `null > 1990` or `null <= 1990` and will exclude these records.